# Creating two dimensional list out of other lists that are not the same size

Tags: python, rich

I have four lists

```py
apps = ["App 1", "App 2", "App 3", "App 4"]
devices = ["device1"]
groups = ["group1", "group2", "group3", "group4"]
rules_name = ["rule1", "rule2", "rule3", "rule4", "rule5"]
```

and I need to iterate over each list adding the index of each list to it's correct index in the new list, something like this...

The `None` would indicate that there are no other items in the list, in this case the `device` list

```py
rows = [ 
    [apps[0], devices[0], groups[0], group_rules[0]],
    [apps[1], None ,groups[1], group_rules[1]],
    [apps[2], None ,groups[2], group_rules[2]],
    [apps[3], None ,groups[3], group_rules[3]],
    [apps[4], None ,groups[4], group_rules[4]],
    # The rows list can have any number of rows based on the size of the lists above.
]
```

I've tried looping over each list which just created a pyramid of loops and did not give the correct results. I also tried list comprehension but I'm not super well versed in those so maybe I did it wrong.

For what it's worth, I'm using the [Rich](https://github.com/Textualize/rich) library which requires either a list of rows or adding a bunch of

```py
table.add_row("App1", "Device1", "group1", "rule1")
```

However, I'm not sure how to make that dynamic as the original four lists will vary in size each time I run this code.

Comment: The result of [rows] can have any number of rows. This was just an example.

Comment: Not to be argumentative but it sounds like we're being a bit pedantic as these are examples which thought would have been clear. It's happily fixed now and [rows] should be accurate to the apps, devices, groups, and rules_name lists.

Comment: If the list `devices` also had e.g. "device3" and "device4", but no "device2", what should the output look like?

Comment: It wouldn't need to count in order the number of devices. So in your example, if there's no "device2" then that's fine, it should just needs to display a list of devices. e.g. ["device1", "device3", "device4"]

Comment: So should "device3" then be in the second row?

Comment: It seems like you just want `itertools.zip_longest`, but from the example it's not 100% clear. Is this what you are after? `list(zip_longest(apps, devices, groups, rules_name))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterate over two lists with different lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44000727/iterate-over-two-lists-with-different-lengths)

Comment: Tom A. was able to answer the question and it's marked as accepted below. Thanks everyone for trying to help and sorry if I wasn't clear on what I was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be solved by obtaining the size of the longest list and iterating over that amount times, each time checking whether the size of each list is lesser than the current index. if it is larger you simply append the current item in that index of the list, otherwise put None.

```
apps = ["App 1", "App 2", "App 3", "App 4"]
devices = ["device1"]
groups = ["group1", "group2", "group3", "group4"]
rules_name = ["rule1", "rule2", "rule3", "rule4", "rule5"]

#get length of all lists
apps_len = len(apps)
devices_len = len(devices)
groups_len = len(groups)
rules_name_len = len(rules_name)

#determine number of rows based on the longest list
max_size = max(apps_len, devices_len, groups_len, rules_name_len)
rows = []

for i in range(max_size):
    current_row = []
    if i < apps_len: 
        current_row.append(apps[i]) 
    else:
        current_row.append(None)
    if i < devices_len: 
        current_row.append(devices[i]) 
    else:
        current_row.append(None)
    if i < groups_len: 
        current_row.append(groups[i]) 
    else:
        current_row.append(None)
    if i < rules_name_len: 
        current_row.append(rules_name[i]) 
    else:
        current_row.append(None)

    rows.append(current_row)
```